# Check if the value of key in an array of objects is same iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'd an `NSArray` with some dictionaries.which has some keys and values.which I'm showing in a tableview. I'd put the section header title is one of the value of a key in that dictionary i.e. like ddDate value. The problem is the same ddDate values needs to come under the same section. So I need to create my array according to that.

```
responseDict (
        {
        xx = 16;
        yy = 17;
        aa = 0;
        bb = 6;
        cc = 2016;
       ddDate = "17-06-2016";
    },
        {
        xx = 17;
        yy = 17;
        aa = 0;
        bb = 6;
        cc = 2016;

        ddDate = "17-06-2016";

    },
        {
        xx = 18;
        yy = 17;
        aa = 0;
        bb = 6;
        cc = 2016;

        ddDate = "18-06-2016";

    }
```

ie date is the section title. And those who had the same ddDate values under one section. Can anybody guide me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are using swift or objective-c?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala obj-C

Comment: Iterate through `responseDict` (which is actually an array) - extracting the `ddDate` value from the dictionary and use it as the key to another dictionary that holds `NSMutableArrays` - get the array from this dictionary (or create a new array if there isn't one for this key) and add the `responseDict` element (which actually is a dictionary) to this array.  Once you are done, extract the keys from the dictionary into an array (this is all of your `ddDate` values).  Use this array for your sections and retrieve the array from the dictionary based on the section value for the rows

Comment: @Paulw11 can u give me some  codes to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to build two data structures; An array of `ddDate` values; this will be your section information and a dictionary of arrays, keyed by the `ddDate` values; this will be your row data.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sections;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *rows;

- (void)processJSONData:(NSArray *)inputArray {

    NSMutableDictionary *extractedData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in inputArray) {
        NSString *ddDate = dict["ddDate"];
        NSMutableArray *rowArray = extractedData[ddDate];
        if (rowArray == nil) {
            rowArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            extractedData[ddDate] = rowArray;
        }
        [rowArray addObject:dict];
    }

    self.sections = [extractedData allKeys];
    self.rows = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:extractedData];
}
```

You might like to sort the `self.sections` array.

The number of sections is `self.sections.count` and the number of rows in a section are `self.rows[self.sections[indexPath.section]].count`

Comment: Can u pls clarify did u mean extractedData[ddDict] ,or  extractedData[dict] ;?

Comment: can u pls clarify how will i handle this in cellforrowatindexpath with index path.section

Comment: `NSArray *rowArray = self.rows[self.sections[indexPath.section]]; NSDictionary *row = rowArray[indexPath.row];`

Comment: Please clarify it, how can I use it on numberOfItemsInSection on collection view

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create custom Arrays then compare dates, and if the date is same then add it under one header title else move it to the next header title. As such i don't see a shortcut out here.